# Es posible poner una variable como propiedad de un objeto anónimo en c#?

Tags: c#

Actualmente se pueden crear objetos anónimos en C# de esta forma:

```
var anonimo = new {prop1= "prop1", prop2= "prop2", prop3="prop3" };
```

Es posible crear el mismo objeto pero pasandole una variable como nombre de la propiedad? Ejemplo:

```
var prop="propstring";

var anonimo = new {prop= "prop1"};
```

de manera que la propiedad quede como "propstring" y no como "prop"???

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿en qué escenario te sería de utilidad?

Comment: fijate que es buena pregunta en Vb.net  se utiliza algo asi Dim product2 = New With {Key .Name = "paperclips", Key .Value= 1.29}  lo cual crea un objeto asi {paperclips=1.29}

Comment: fijate esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/6044525/73749. La pregunta es porque?

Comment: Porque quiero poder crearlo dinámicamente. Y en la respuesta que recibo del servidor nunca se que columnas me trae sino que puede variar. Eso viene en un diccionario pero es tedioso estar  recoriendo los diccionarios, así que me gustaría poder crear un objeto con sus props en tiempo de ejecución pero para saber la key del diccionario necesito hacer algo así dato["dato"] lo cual no puedi pasar como propiedad a un objeto anónimo. En pocas palabras necesito crear objetos y crearles propiedades a partir de un string a esos objetos para evitar lidiar con diccionarios. Y no quiero usar Datatables

Comment: Lo más cercano que he visto a eso es dapper que mapea de un objeto a otro,  pero me gustaría ojala quedara tipado y todo el objeto como si hubiese sido una clase o modelo que yo había definido con sus propiedades

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar una una hastable el cual te permite meter key y value.

Te dejo un ejemplo espero que te sea de utilidad

```
Hashtable openWith = new Hashtable();


// Las keys no pueden ser duplicadas.
openWith.Add("txt", "notepad.exe");
openWith.Add("bmp", "paint.exe");
openWith.Add("dib", "paint.exe");
openWith.Add("rtf", "wordpad.exe");

// Saco todos los pares key/value
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in openWith)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
}
Console.WriteLine(openWith["rtf"]);//saca la clave especifica
```

Comment: Esto de entrada, no sirve. VS marca error al crear el objeto anónimo. En ese ejemplo no se crea ningún objeto anónimo

Answer (score -1):

Puedes trabajar con dynamic y crear tu objeto a partir de un json:

```
var prop = "propstring";

var myJsonString = "{ \"" + prop + "\":\"prop1\", \"prop2\": \"prop2\", \"prop3\": \"prop3\" }";
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJsonString);
```

Después para acceder a tu propiedad:

```
string value = results[prop];
```

Es necesario instalar los siguientes NuGet:
Microsoft.CSharp,
Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Gracias pero dynamic no es un objeto anónimo